# Retrieve object generically from within another object

Tags: java, reflection

Is there a Java library to retrieve an object using a String representation of the 'path' to that object?

For example, say I have an object

```
 Map<String, Map<Integer, Map<String, String>>> myMap;
```

myMap contains data like this

```
"Dog"->[1,["name","Rex"]],[2,["name","Bowwowser"]]
```

Ideally I'm looking for a method where I can pass in "Dog.1.name" (and maybe the String.class) and receive back a String containing "Rex". I'm not quite sure what the technical name for this is though the concept seems similar to XPath and accessing data within a model in JSTL.

Answer (score 0):

[JXPath](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-jxpath/) will at least get you close.  I haven't tested this particular example, but you'd be looking at something similar to:

```
JXPathContext context = new JXPathContext(myMap);
String firstDogName = (String)context.getValue("Dog/1/name");
```

However, according to their documentation, JXPath currently only supports `String`-keyed maps; but if you replaced your `Map<Integer, Foo>` with a `List<Foo>` you'd be set.